# Getting remote address behined a proxy

Tags: java, serversocket

My code create a server socket

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort);
```

and listens on it for new connections

```
Socket connection = serverSocket.accept();
```

I am trying to find the IP of the client.

```
connection.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
```

BUT when my client is behind a proxy, this will return the proxy ip. How can I get the client ip?

Comment: You can't, unless the client sends it to you.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an HTTP connection the proxy *might* pass the client's info along in an [X-Forwarded-For header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For), but it's up to the proxy configuration what it tells you.